# How to not show shadow through transparent shape in figma

Tags: drop-shadow, figma

In figma, I have a rectangle shape which is white with 50% transparency.  I want to apply a shadow only to the outside of this shape, but when I apply the 'drop shadow' effect I see the shadow behind the shape - the shape turns slightly grey.

I was hoping to make it work like CSS box-shadow whereby the shadow only appears outside of the shape.  Is there a way to make it do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this but you could achieve a similar-looking effect using a masking layer. It's hacky but it does the job thou

[image]